# Quick Tag Editor shortcut key in Aptana

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana, dreamweaver, aptana3

In dreamweaver we have Ctrl+T for Quick Tag Editor, in other words we can select part of our text and then press Ctrl+T and then we can select a tag and dreamweaver will add start tag and end tag automatically to selected area,

Is there any shortcut key like this in Aptana ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ctrl+Shift+W` will wrap the selected text with an open and close tag which you can change

Comment: For Mac it is still Ctrl. Not Command. (OSX 10.7.5, Aptana 3.4.2.~)